# Unable to install warbleR package using Mac OS

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, install.packages

When trying to install the `warbleR` package, I keep getting this error message:

```
> install.packages("warbleR")
also installing the dependency ‘bioacoustics’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
warbleR 1.1.14 1.1.15             FALSE

Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘bioacoustics’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘bioacoustics’, ‘warbleR’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/bioacoustics_0.1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 834645 bytes (815 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 815 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/warbleR_1.1.15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2348150 bytes (2.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘bioacoustics’ ...
** package ‘bioacoustics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
configure: CXX: clang++ -std=gnu++11
checking for cmake... not found
configure: error: Could not find cmake
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘bioacoustics’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/bioacoustics’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bioacoustics’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘bioacoustics’ is not available for package ‘warbleR’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/warbleR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘warbleR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/z9/6d_1kkxd0jxcj0r88hng7crm0000gn/T/RtmpSUXFDU/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: have you tried answering "no"  to the question?

Comment: Yes, but R still returns _non-zero exit status_ for the package.

Comment: can you show us the full output that's printed when you say "no"?

Comment: Ok just edited my question.

Comment: I think the key error (in your original question) is `checking whether the C compiler works... no`. You seem to be using OSX, so `xcode-select --install` in a terminal may help.

Comment: oh, I see: it's "Package which is **only** available in source form" (emphasis added); I'm used to "later version is available in source form", in which case you can get away with saying "no". @neilfws is right.

Comment: Obviously not enough rep to accept @neilfws answer. anyway thanks to both of you.

Comment: I will accept @neilfws answer as soon as I have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. I can post it as an answer if you like, if it solved your problem.

Comment: you are right. would be great if you could post it as an answer since it completely solved my problem.

Comment: @neilfws. ok I was a little too hasty here. I installed Xcode, but still keep getting a new  error (see edited question).

Comment: The new error indicates that you don't have `cmake`. You could try installing it using a .dmg [from this site](https://cmake.org/download/), or if you are a homebrew user, `brew install cmake`.

Comment: once it works, you are allowed to write up the answer to your own question and accept it (indeed, you are encouraged to if @neilfws doesn't feel like doing it).

Comment: thanks @BenBolker  for your advice! As @neilfws pointed out, homebrew and `brew install cmake` solved the problem. Lets see if he feels like posting this as an answer, because i think he deserves the credits here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @neilfws pointed out, this could be solved with homebrew running `brew install cmake`.